# Как в Delphi проверить, что строка равна одной кавычке (')?

Tags: delphi

Если задать так: `if s='''` то воспримет как пара кавычек(открытие и закрытие) и новая открытая кавычка. А нужно чтоб проверилось что строка равна кавычке. Двойные кавычки не подойдут, нужно чтоб именно одинарной строке равнялась строка.

Как в Delphi можно задать проверку на то что строка равна **одинарной кавычке** (')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно попробовать сравнить с кодом кавычки.

```
S := '''';
if S = #39 then //если только один символ
//или
if S[i] = #39 then //если несколько символов в строке
```

В ином же случае, используйте экранирование - дублированная одинарная кавычка **(две подряд идущие одинарные кавычки `S := '''';` -> в результате дает одну одинарную кавычку в строке)**.

```
S := '''';
if S = '''' then ...
```

Comment: Дело в том что мне нужна именно одна кавычка. То есть вариант '''' не подойдет. #39 это код одной кавычки?

Comment: Двойные кавычки имеется ввиду не `"`, а `''`.

Это и есть экранирование в действии, в результате у вас в строке будет только одна кавычка. Например, если вам нужно написать некоторую фразу в одинарных кавычках и использовать ее в строковой переменной то:

    S := 'Моя ''любимая'' фраза';

На деле будет выглядеть как: Моя 'любимая' фраза

Comment: в двойные кавычки заключить одинарную? но ведь Delphi не воспринимает двойные кавычки как начало строки

Comment: Пара одинарных кавычек = одна одинарная кавычка. Я даже пример вам привел. Двойные кавычки, видимо, не правильное выражение, сейчас поправлю.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался вроде.